# Where should I store an encryption key for php?

Tags: php, security, encryption, administration

I'm writing a php application that accepts sensitive customer data, and so I need to encrypt it before storing it in a mysql database. I'm going to use mysql's built-in AES functionality to do column-level encryption.

I want to avoid storing the encryption key on the server, and so i'm going to provide a web-page for an administrator to log-in, and enter the encryption key. I want to store this key in memory while the application is running, but never permanently to disk.

What is the best way to do this?

Can I modify the $_SERVER array to store information between requests? Can I store the key with apache in some way? Maybe shared memory?

Comment: Though I think your idea itself is bad, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html

Comment: What happens if the machine spontaneously reboots (or you need to reboot it).  Does the key just disappear? Or is the application offline until the Admin can look up the key from backup somewhere and enter it manually.  This could be a slow process.

Comment: What happens if the admin uploads the wrong key or a corrupt key accidentally? Until someone notices, you're storing data that will never be retrievable, and you won't know which data was produced with the bad key vs the good one except when you try to decrypt each piece and figure out which ones are not recoverable.

Comment: @genesis: I agree an attacker could still view the contents of memory, but I need to co-operate with the IT department of my customer, and they don't want this stored in a file.

Comment: Yeah, this has a whole bunch of bad side effects as far as I can figure.

Comment: @Kibbee: Exactly. They customer has an IT department that was ok with this procedure.

Comment: No, Matt. `$_SESSION` stores key-value pairs **on disk**, and they are only accessible to the **single user** with the matching session cookie, not all users of the application.

Comment: @Dan Grossman: Very good point... I didn't think of that

Comment: @ Matt H: The key is application-wide

Comment: @Dan Regardless of where you store the key, the server should validate it on startup.  (You can validate the key by decrypting the contents of a previously encrypted field whose value is known.)

Comment: Best not to use AES as many servers store their databases on another server, which means more data transfer outside of your control. Better to encrypt in PHP before sending to SQL. Use `openssl` or better still an up to date ready made popular encryption library.

Comment: sidenote as this Q came up in the feed today: AES ecryption on MySQL is not suitable for encrytion. If you want SAFE data you need to encrypt it outside of MySQL and so MySQL only knows the encrypted data and can't extrapolate the plaintext. MySQL can easily have various action and event trackers which will log decrypted data into server log files, causing a significant security compromise if the MySQL is breached (for example a MySQL server can be compromised and the PHP server that interacts with it can remain secure).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up storing the encryption key in an in-memory table. All access to the database is done through a set of stored procedures; The stored procedures include the ability to do key management (i.e. insert key to memory-table, change keys, check if a key has been entered etc.), as well as store/retrieve application data.

With this design, the database credentials left on the application server only have the authorization to query through the set of defined procedures, and have no way to read the encryption key directly.

I liked this approach because:

1. The key isn't stored on the file system - preventing issues with hardware disposal at end-of-life, and from prying eyes of system administrators
2. The application code can't get access to the key (other than while entering it), so the only place it will ever reside is within the database process.
3. All logic for encryption/decryption is embedded within the SQL queries, so don't need to worry about application code doing it correctly - Nice for maintenance.

Comment: What do you do if the server crashes? The in-memory table with the key will be lost and your data can't be accessed anymore?

Answer (score 7):

Rather than rely on MySQL AES for encryption, why not use PHP's native openssl encryption scheme (a PECL extension).  This requires a private and public key, public to encrypt, private to decrypt, and the keys can be kept in separate places.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to create a RAM disk and store the key there.

Answer (score 2):

The safest place to store any kind of encryption key is on the server NOT in the database, and make sure it is owned by root and not readable by others.

Comment: and how will client access that? BTW, databse is on SERVER, too ;)

Comment: Client doesn't need access to it. The author's assumption that having the key re-uploaded by the administrator every time the application starts is a good idea is poor. For one thing, if the admin accidentally bungles the key or uploads the wrong file one time, all the data stored with it won't be retrievable and nobody will know which records were encrypted with which key.

Comment: @serialworm You suggested making sure only root can read the file, but php probably won't be running as the root user...

Comment: Good point. I did notice that he mentioned he wanted to avoid storing it on the server, but I know the dangers of storing keys in the database.

Comment: Another good point.  I agree with that.  However I still maintain that having the file owned by the webserver user (apache) or whatever will still be more secure than storing in a database.

Comment: Due to Dan's point that I will risk creating non-recoverable encrypted data if an IT person uploads the wrong key, i'm going to suggest that the key be stored on the filesystem. Thanks for all the responses!

Comment: @Levi See my point above.  You have the same problem even if the key is stored on the filesystem (the probability is much lower, but the key file can still become corrupted or accidentally replaced).  You should always validate the key on startup, no matter where it is stored.

Comment: I'm going to store an encrypted field in the database that I know the contents of - call this value $special. When I install the application, I will choose some default key to encrypt $special under. When the application has started-up, and the administrator attempts to upload the encryption key, it will ensure that $special decrypts to the known contents. To change keys, I will just need to store the updated encryption of the $special field.

Comment: Another thing that I forgot to mention is that this data can be stored short-term - so the current database data could be purged once an encryption key has been changed.

Comment: I would have put the above into an answer, but I don't have enough reputation

Comment: The whole point of AES encryption is to make your data unreadable if your DB becomes compromised.  I typically see keys and salts stored directly in the PHP inside of a config or headers file.  The rationale behind this is that, IF someone is looking at your PHP, you've already lost no matter how you store it because they just have to find the function call that you wrote for making decryption happen.  If they find your key along the way, it's just damage that was already unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

Write a php config file and store it in your home directory. Allow only php to have access to it.

```
$cryptKey = "aac1ebadcfabdef72376acd" ;
```

Include at the top of every php page that uses the encryption key using an absolute path to the home folder. This folder is not accessible to the end user.