# Where to store private key for encryption in PHP environment

Tags: php, encryption

In my database I store information which is encrypted and decrypted on the fly via a PHP-class.

Per application I use a private key appended with a user key to make sure the decryption only succeeds when a user tries to decrypt its own data.

The user 'key' is stored in the database; but the private key (application level) is stored as txt-file in the FS. Off course 'above' the web-root.

Considerations: 
- If the database gets hacked: they end up with one part of the key, and encrypted data
- If PHP-stops or is corrupt: they end up with a single page with only `include('../private/private.php')` in it.
- If NGINX fails: the connection is 'just' dropped.

The only scenario I can think of is the corruption of the system itself. But the server runs a firewall, is updated regularly, runs fail2ban and only the services needed are run. SSH logins only via key-access etc etc

I was wondering if this is the 'best' practice. 
Or if there is a better way to do this kind of encryption with above specifications?
What would be the correct access-rights to the key-file?

At the moment the database and webserver are both on the same server facing the internet. Is it better to split them and create an internet facing server with only the webserver; and put the database server and key-file on a different server in a private network?

edit: the private key to encrypt the data is build up by two components:
`$key = $app_key . $user_key`

Comment: correct access rights to the key-file would be `-r--------` or `400`, and the webserver user as owner. Other than that, it seems you did a fairly good job

Comment: *"I use a private key appended with a user key to make sure the decryption only succeeds when a user tries to decrypt its own data"* I 'm not sure what that means. You keep both keys on the server, so decryption will succeed whenever you want it to. Conversely, if the server gets owned the data is owned as well.

Comment: its a capable start it entirely depends on what level of information you have and just how tight you need to be with security.  For most common scenarios you're fine though you may want to consider running an audit on the daemons running on the OS under to check that there aren't any known attack vectors on them for example ssh'd version etc

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to security.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Jon I updated the question. The decryption key consists of two component: an app-component and a user-specific part.

Comment: Maybe this question needs to be moved to security.stackexchange.com

Comment: @stUrb: I got that. The thing is that you are not asking the user for the user-piece each time, but rather you have it stored in the database. So you can decrypt anytime you like, you don't have to ask the user to supply their piece of the solution.

Comment: Ah That's what you meant. Thats true indeed; there is a group of super-users who, besides the user himself, need to be able to decrypt the information stored. That's why the user_component is stored in the user-row.

Answer (score 2):

> I was wondering if this is the 'best' practice. Or if there is a
>   better way to do this kind of encryption with above specifications?
>   What would be the correct access-rights to the key-file?

**Hard to implement**

To be perfectly secure you would need to generate a private-public key pair on an HSM (hardware security module) such as a smartcard or an HSM box. The generated private key is created inside the HSM and can never leave the HSM, it can only be used for decrypt / sign operations inside the HSM itself, however it can never be read off the HSM. In this case if someone hacks your server, or even get complete control over your server, they can never get hold of the private key stored inside HSM. Depending on number of decrypt / sign operations required on your server you would need a reasonably performing HSM to decrypt required data. Accomplishing this task in pure PHP is however a long way to go ( you could implement your own C++ extension or use inter-process communication with a process that is able interact with HSMs)

**Easier to implement**

It is important to harden your server and minimize the attack vector as much as you possibly can. This mainly includes assigning appropriate permissions to files and database. Have a look at [this](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10) for some good security practices. 
To add my few cents you can use:

1. [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) for in memory storage of your private key in php (this will also give you a boost in performance in compare with constanlty reading a key from a file). You would need to implement some secure mechanism (such as you entering a passcode ) to decrypt /restore an encrypted key into the APC every time you restart the web server.
2. Something like [ionCube](http://www.ioncube.com/) for encrypting and protecting your PHP scripts
3. Control you deployment process using an application container such as [docker](https://www.docker.com/what-docker)

> At the moment the database and webserver are both on the same server
>   facing the internet. Is it better to split them and create an internet
>   facing server with only the webserver; and put the database server and
>   key-file on a different server in a private network?

Yes, separating the webserver from database server is definitely a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can load the key into APC or something similar.  This would require human input during boot (or perhaps kicked off from a more secured server).  This would mean the key is never stored in any file on the server.

It's not perfect, but it's better than the more typical approach of using a local file.

q.v., [Where should I store an encryption key for php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767839/where-should-i-store-an-encryption-key-for-php)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the OWASP Cryptographic Storage Cheat Sheet and its recommendations. Rule 2.1.5.4: Protects key in a key vaults. Keys should not be stored on the application or web server.